# How to solve react-table error:- TypeError: plugin is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I create a basic react table using react-table and useTable hooks. I get this error:

> `TypeError: plugin is not a function.`

How do I solve this error?

Here is my code:

```js
import Reactt,{ useMemo } from 'react'
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import COLUMNS from "./columns";
import MOCK_DATA from '../MOCK_DATA.json'
import '../table.css'
const BasicTable = () => {
const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, []);   
const tableInstance = useTable(
 columns,
 data,
 )
 const {getTableProps,getTableBodyProps,headerGroups,rows,prepareRow}= tableInstance
  return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
         <thead>
            {
              headerGroups.map((headerGroup)=>(
               <tr{...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                 {headerGroup.headers.map((column)=>(
                    <th{...column.getHeaderGroups()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
               ))} </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {
                        rows.map((row)=>{
                            prepareRow(row)
                            return(
                                <tr{...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {row.cells.map((cell)=>{
                                return <td{...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('cell')}</td>
                                })}
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }  
export default BasicTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `columns` and `data` as an options object. Do this instead

```
useTable({columns,data})
```

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#usetable

Answer (score 0):

Also not sure if it would mess up your code but you wrote "`import Reactt`" instead of "`import React`"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).